# FizzBuzz implementation

Tags: java, interview-questions, fizzbuzz

The common [FizzBuzz](http://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/) implementation I saw is using a check for % 15 for printing "FizzBuzz"

Would you let me know if there is anything wrong / better with this approach?

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            boolean fizzOrBuzz = false;
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("Fizz");
                fizzOrBuzz = true;
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("Buzz");
                fizzOrBuzz = true;
            }

            if (fizzOrBuzz) {
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version is optimized for the computer. Winston's version is optimized for the human. Got to trust a compiler that it can do a good job at re-shuffling and optimizing the code. Also, it is possible that a single io statement will work faster than two separate ones. You should race your version against the other one.

Comment: I'll tell you why I like my version better (only for the interview context) 1) maintainability - you can externalize Fizz and Buzz as strings, you don't need to externalize FizzBuzz 2) DRY, a user writing the above code is thinking in terms of not repeating oneself, which I like

Comment: +1 but, use a *StringBuilder* and not 100 * System.out.println(..), and, *Integer.valueOf(i)*

Comment: @cl-r thanks, I will keep it at the original so the comments will still make sense, thanks for the feedback

Comment: FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition is the best implementation there is: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition ;D

Answer (score 29):

Let's compare your version to the `% 15` version:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz")
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Fizz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Buzz");
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `% 15` version is simpler and easier to read. This version neatly delineates the problem into the 4 different cases, and handles each case. In contrast, your version introduces a boolean logic flag (which I consider to be a significant anti-pattern) and a not entirely intuitive dependence on the order of the if statements.

Comment: 15 is a "magic number" here. I'd suggest using `(3 * 5)` instead. The compiler should convert it to 15...

Comment: @Ron - So is, `"FizzBuzz"`, by this criteria.  Not that you're _wrong_ necessarily, but for these types of 'trivia' questions, the necessity of declaring everything is usually relaxed slightly.  For instance, strictly speaking, for production-level code, **all** the numbers and strings referenced/printed here should be captured as named constants.

Comment: @X-Zero, would you capture the 3 as a constant, what would you call it?

Comment: @Winston - The general problem with this is it's basically a 'contrived' example, so it can be hard to get _good_ names for this.  Especially as what the test has is essentially 'multiple' checks - continuing to decompose this would likely result in some sort of array/table structure (yeah... I know... heading to outer-space architecture).  So, `MATCH` maybe?  `CONDITION`?  Urgh.  Which is why these kinds of conventions are relaxed for these kinds of tests; the test is for basic coding ability, not (necessarily) full abstraction skills.

Comment: I would move if-for-15 inside if-for-5, if you can't divide a number by 3, certainly can't divide by 15, save 4/5 of checks for all numbers

Answer (score 6):

It looks fine. `String.valueOf()` is unnecessary, `System.out.println(i)` would print the same but it is still OK. This test is used only to make sure that the interviewee can write code as the linked site says:

> This sort of question won’t identify great programmers, but it will identify the weak ones. 
>   And that’s definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that's (IMHO) a little better for humans than yours and better for computers as well:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String value;
            switch (i % 15) {
            case  3:
            case  6:
            case  9:
            case 12:  // divisible by 3, print Fizz
                value = "Fizz";
                break;
            case  5:
            case 10:  // divisible by 5, print Buzz
                value = "Buzz";
                break;
            case  0:  // divisible by 3 and by 5, print FizzBuzz
                value = "FizzBuzz";
                break;
            default:  // else print the number
                value = Integer.toString(i);
            }
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The comments provide information to humans (but they could still see it on their own) and there's only one `System.out.println` call per `i`.

**EDIT:** This is another way to fizz-buzz (focus: DRY):

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String EMPTY = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String value = EMPTY;
            if (i % 3 == 0) value += "Fizz";
            if (i % 5 == 0) value += "Buzz";
            if (value == EMPTY) value += i;
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** yet another, using `StringBuilder`, DRY as well:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1000);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            final int length = builder.length();
            if (i % 3 == 0) builder.append("Fizz");
            if (i % 5 == 0) builder.append("Buzz");
            if (length == builder.length()) builder.append(i);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder seems a faster approach than += in this case

Comment: @EranMedan - Are you sure of this?  `StringBuilder` is good because `N` appends doesn't lead to `N` allocations, however here `N` is at most 2, which is a small enough number that it likely won't make a difference, and it's quite likely to be 1, which means no difference at all (or maybe worse, as `StringBuilder` probably does an extra allocation for that 1 append).

Comment: @asveikau - you are probably right, I guess this will be over optimization to find out exactly which is faster :)

Comment: I'm aware of StringBuilder - which I use all the time in String heavy code - and thought along the lines of [asveikau](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/4029/asveikau). `+=` is less "noisy" (also the reason for my avoidance of `Integer.toString()`) and it won't make much of a difference as there's at most two concatenations. Btw.: I'd have used StringBuilder like this: declare before the loop, initialize with capacity set to `8`, cleared and reuse per iteration. Creating it inside the loop wouldn't improve much.

Comment: see above for another version using `StringBuilder` - but only one call to `System.out.println(...)`.

Comment: if edit 1 you dont have to do += here right? -             if (value == EMPTY) value += i;

Answer (score 3):

They are certainly not perfects, but I've tried some ways to optimize the test, here the result (I have had numbers to keep trace of good responses) , and I use a StringBuilder to avoid initialization of output IO:

```
package exercices;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.memneuroo.outils.communs.utilitaires.EnvPrm;

public class FizzBuzz {
    // time for cum with nbIter=30 > 300; 30 ~= 3000
    static final int nbIter = 30;
    static final String sep = "_";

    static long ifNested() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIter; i++) {
            sb.append(//
            i % 15 == 0 //
                ? "FizzBuzz" //
                : (i % 3 == 0 //
                    ? "Fizz"//
                    : (i % 5 == 0//
                        ? "Buzz" //
                        : i)));// sb.append(sep);
        }
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("ifNested\t%20d\n", totT);
        // sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE); System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;
    }

    static long stringPlus() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIter; i++) {
            String x = "";
            x += (i % 3 == 0) ? "Fizz" : "";
            x += (i % 5 == 0) ? "Buzz" : "";
            if (x.isEmpty()) { // MODIF
                x += Integer.toString(i);
            }
            sb.append(x);// sb.append(sep);
        }
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("stringPlus\t%20d\n", totT);
        // sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE); System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;
    }

    static long withIf() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIter; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                sb.append("Fizz");
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    sb.append("Buzz");
                }
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                sb.append("Buzz");
            } else {
                sb.append(i);
            }// sb.append(sep);
        }
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("withIf\t\t%20d\n", totT);
        // sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE);System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;
    }

    static long withArray() {
        final String[] lis = {"FizzBuzz", "", "", "Fizz", "", "Buzz", "Fizz",
            "", "", "Fizz", "Buzz", "", "Fizz", "", "",};
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIter; i++) {
            final String pos = lis[i % 15];
            sb.append(((0 == pos.length()) ? i : pos));// sb.append(sep);
        }
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("withArray\t%20d\n", totT);
        // sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE); System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;
    }

    static long withTable() {
        final Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = new Hashtable<>(8);
        ht.put(0, "FizzBuzz");
        ht.put(3, "Fizz");
        ht.put(5, "Buzz");
        ht.put(6, "Fizz");
        ht.put(9, "Fizz");
        ht.put(10, "Buzz");
        ht.put(12, "Buzz");
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIter; i++) {
            final String s = ht.get(i % 15);
            // MODIF
            // http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1196563-2/java/general-java/if-null-object-if-objet-null/#post6561766
            // sb.append((null == s ? i : s));// sb.append(sep);
            if (null == s) {
                sb.append(i);
            } else {
                sb.append(s);
            }
        }
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("withTable\t%20d\n", totT);
        // sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE); System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;

    }

    static int recursive(final StringBuilder sb, final int n) {
        if (0 == n) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            sb.insert(0, "Fizz");
            if (n % 5 == 0) {
                sb.insert(0, "Buzz");
            }
        } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
            sb.insert(0, "Buzz");
        } else {
            sb.insert(0, n);
        }
        return n + recursive(sb, n - 1);
    }

    static long recursive() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        final long t = System.nanoTime();
        recursive(sb, nbIter);
        final long totT = System.nanoTime() - t;
        System.out.format("recursive\t%20d\n", totT);
        sb.append(EnvPrm.NEWLINE);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return totT;
    }

    /*** @param args */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        long cum = 0L, cum2 = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("------ " + i + " -----");
            final long totSb = stringPlus();
            final long totIn = ifNested();
            final long totWi = withIf();
            final long totWa = withArray();
            final long totWt = withTable();
            final long totRe = recursive();
            System.out.format("... stringPlus/withIf :%5d\n", (totSb * 100)
                / totWi);
            System.out.format("...   ifNested/withIf :%5d\n", (totIn * 100)
                / totWi);
            System.out.format("...  withArray/withIf :%5d\n", (totWa * 100)
                / totWi);
            System.out.format("...  withTable/withIf :%5d\n", (totWt * 100)
                / totWi);
            System.out.format("...  recursive/withIf :%5d\n", (totRe * 100)
                / totWi);
            cum += totIn + totSb + totWi + totWa + totWt + totRe;
            System.out.println("CUMUL (SECOND) == " + cum / 100000000 + "."
                + cum % 100000000 + "\t , diff: " + (cum - cum2));
            cum2 = cum;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output :

```
------ 0 -----
stringPlus                529397
ifNested                  643657
withIf                     27657
withArray                  43581
withTable                  40788
recursive                  87441
12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314BuzzFizz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829BuzzFizz

... stringPlus/withIf : 1914
...   ifNested/withIf : 2327
...  withArray/withIf :  157
...  withTable/withIf :  147
...  recursive/withIf :  316
CUMUL (SECOND) == 0.1372521  , diff: 1372521
------ 1 -----
stringPlus                345295
ifNested                   88280
withIf                     88279
withArray                  88838
withTable                 101689
recursive                  93308
12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314BuzzFizz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829BuzzFizz

... stringPlus/withIf :  391
...   ifNested/withIf :  100
...  withArray/withIf :  100
...  withTable/withIf :  115
...  recursive/withIf :  105
CUMUL (SECOND) == 0.2178210  , diff: 805689
------ 2 -----
stringPlus                380216
ifNested                   36597
withIf                     20953
withArray                  60063
withTable                  91352
recursive                 111467
12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314BuzzFizz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829BuzzFizz

... stringPlus/withIf : 1814
...   ifNested/withIf :  174
...  withArray/withIf :  286
...  withTable/withIf :  435
...  recursive/withIf :  531
CUMUL (SECOND) == 0.2878858  , diff: 700648
------ 3 -----
stringPlus                489168
ifNested                   29613
withIf                     22070
withArray                  27099
withTable                  27378
recursive                  91911
12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314BuzzFizz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829BuzzFizz

... stringPlus/withIf : 2216
...   ifNested/withIf :  134
...  withArray/withIf :  122
...  withTable/withIf :  124
...  recursive/withIf :  416
CUMUL (SECOND) == 0.3566097  , diff: 687239
------ 4 -----
stringPlus                143035
ifNested                   24025
withIf                     15924
withArray                  23187
withTable                  26819
recursive                  87162
12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314BuzzFizz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829BuzzFizz

... stringPlus/withIf :  898
...   ifNested/withIf :  150
...  withArray/withIf :  145
...  withTable/withIf :  168
...  recursive/withIf :  547
CUMUL (SECOND) == 0.3886249  , diff: 320152
```

Comment: StringBuilder is based on a `char[16]`. You should set the initial capacity to a value larger than the String you want to create - or you worsen the performance, as StringBuilder has to grow (allocate new `char[]`, copy old data). You should also be aware of how [`System.nanoTime()`](stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html) works and the issues it has. And I'd advise you to do a lot more iterations. I think you mainly measure the time for `System.out.println()` right now, the other operations probably take very little time compared to a system call.

Comment: Tell me, have you ever heard of the concept *over-engineering*...?

Comment: @Max I do, but is this site is done for some researches or not? Is for comfortable eyes, or to try to understand how some ways are better ? So you can choose and compare the faster, the easy to read, or interrogate the code to find missing optimization.

Comment: See [Rules for optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization). IMHO Winston Ewert provided the best answer.

Comment: explain math in withTable code please?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni - It is not a math answer, but Java code sample, no abstraction but algorithm application

Comment: never mine I read the other answer by @arne and understood